# Use annotate and Case with different field types in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-annotate

I have a model with those field:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='child')
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    text_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to make a query on that model using annotate and Case with those rules:

- When parent is null it returns the text_code field
- When parent is not null it returns parent__number field

I can make it with SQL in PostgreSQL like:

```
CASE WHEN "ModelA"."parent_id" IS NOT NULL 
    THEN T3."number"**::integer** 
ELSE "ModelA"."text_code"**::integer** END AS "control_field"
```

But I can't make that with Django ORM. I've tried the following:

```
query = ModelA.objects.all().select_related('parent').annotate(
    control_field=Case(
        When(parent_id__isnull=False, then='parent__number'),
        default='text_code',
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ),
)
```

But when I call query result, it rase the following error:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: CASE types character varying and integer cannot be matched

I know it is an Database error, because the SQL result from django construct doesn't have the **::integer** add.

```
CASE WHEN "ModelA"."parent_id" IS NOT NULL 
    THEN T3."number" 
ELSE "ModelA"."text_code" END AS "control_field"
```

How can I solve this? I'm working with Django 1.11

Comment: Looks quite unsafe. Why is `text_code` a `CharField`if it is numerical?

Comment: But you can use `Cast` for this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem this field came from another class and it can be numerical or textualc depending on the model

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you so much! I spent two days reading the docs, and couldn't saw that function!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, use Cast:

```
query = ModelA.objects.all().select_related('parent').annotate(
    control_field=Case(
        When(parent_id__isnull=False, then=Cast('parent__number', IntegerField())),
        default=Cast('text_code', IntegerField()),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ),
)
```